# What jQuery selector will give me the first element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get the selection of the first td based on the first row using the class name?

```
<tbody id="logBody">
    <tr class="logArow">
        <td>Log Name</td>
        <td>Log Information</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've gotten this far but got stuck and not sure how to get first child of td....

```
$("#logBody > tr.logArow").first()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example that is close to what you already had:

```
$("#logBody > tr.logArow > td:first")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this. Here's one:

```
$("#logBody td:first-child")
```

For more, browse [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **partial** list of how it can be done:

```
$("#logBody > tr.logArow > td:eq(0)")
$("#logBody > tr.logArow > td").eq(0)
$("#logBody > tr.logArow > td:first-child")
$("#logBody > tr.logArow > td").first()
$("#logBody > tr.logArow > td:first")
$("#logBody > tr.logArow > td").slice(0,1)
```